# apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Input/output error

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to restart apache2 and it failed. I got the message below. It was working before so I don't know what went wrong and how to fix it. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 on windows 10.

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                            [fail]
* The apache2 configtest failed.
 Output of config test was:
apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Input/output error*

 Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Comment: Did you attempt to edit that file form outside the Linux-on-Windows environment? That is, using a Windows editor?

Comment: Yes, I opened it with notepad++ and added phpmyadmin config.

Comment: Ah, you'll want to read this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/ .... in short, you can't do that.

Comment: (I would guess you can fix it by copying that file somewhere else using Explorer, then purge and reinstall Apache. Then using Linux tools, possibly just `cp` from `/mnt/c/…`, put your config back in place. But I'm not sure, haven't actually used Ubuntu on Windows)

Comment: Just one thing to note: Debian derivatives (including Ubuntu) have both *removed* and *purged*. Removed means you've removed the program, but left the configuration behind. If however you're adding/removing programs makes that distinction, you need to purge it (remove the config as well), as the config is what's broken.

Comment: I used purge but the files and folders still exist. I got this message "dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--purge):
 cannot remove old config file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to use Windows Explorer to delete that file. Then you can try the purge again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Microsoft, you must not ["under ANY circumstances, create and/or modify Linux files using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc."](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

If you want to edit a Linux file with a Windows editor, the easiest way is probably something like this (in a bash shell):

1. `cp /path/to/file /mnt/c/whatever`. Where of course *whatever* is some path on your system to store a temporary copy.
2. Edit *whatever* using your favorite Windows editor. It'll need to support Linux line endings, of course.
3. `cp /mnt/c/whatever /path/to/file`.
4. `rm /mnt/c/whatever` (clean up the temporary file—you can also do this from Explorer).

Answer (score 1):

Good day! Editor Notepad ++ only right to modify Linux files in Windows. You only need to set the necessary parameters. Critical: utf-8, the end of the Unix \ Linux line.